# Not intersecting spheres (moving to same) point by collision detection

Tags: java, geometry, collision

i am currently learning java. My goal is it to have a "player "sphere (following mouse coordinates) being followed by "enemies". These are also spheres, chasing the "player".
Every enemy goes straight to it's destination (player coordinates).
Now I've got following problem:
Enemy spheres can intersect which results in multiple enemy spheres laying on top of each other. 
Now my question is: how can i avoid spheres gettin on top of each other but still moving in a specific direction? 
For example: two spheres are moving to a specific point from a slightly different angle. Of course they will collide in some moment but then they should continue going to the point without getting on top of each other, just touching slightly each others edges.

The Enemy Object extends my entity class:

Entity.java:

```
 public class Entity {

 protected double x, y;
 protected double speed;
 protected int size;

 //detecting collision between two spheres

 public boolean isColliding(Ellipse2D.Double sphere1, int size1 Ellipse2D.Double sphere2, int size2) {
      double a = size1/2 + size2/2;
      double dx = sphere1.x - sphere2.x;
      double dy = sphere1.y - sphere2.y;
      return a * a > (dx * dx + dy * dy);
      }

public void move(double gx, double gy, ArrayList<Enemy> enemies, int id) {


    // .... Here comes the code calculating the movement in x and y direction  ....
    // --> stepX and stepY get initialized, the sphere should move in stepX and stepY direction 
    // to get to the destinationcoordinates (gx and gy are the destination coordinates)

     if(isColliding(sphere1, size1, sphere2, size29 {

        //what should happen when two spheres moving to the same point collide?
        //They must not stop moving to the same directory, just 
        //stop overlapping with the colliding sphere!!
 }   
 else {
        //if not colliding: x should get closer to gx, y should get
        // closer to gy
   x += stepX;
   y += stepYy;
 }
 }
 }
```

A Core class contains an ArrayList with all the enemies and on every update this move method above gets called. "enemies" is the ArrayList containing all enemies.

I hope You can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 options

1) Have one sphere stop it's motion until the other sphere gets out of the way.  If you do this, you'll want to arrange for the sphere that stops to move after the sphere that doesn't stop moves, so if the non-stop sphere moves out of the way, the stopping sphere moves too.

2) Average out their movements so they move together.  Eg, if the speed is mx1==2 and my1==2 and mx2==2 and my2==-4, then my1 and my2 = (my1 + my2)/2 ; in this case = -1.

3) Have one sphere continue on course and the other sphere adjust.  In the previous example, you'd leave my1==2 and set my2=2

Good luck!

Comment: I would go with "check if they intersect, separate if they do". This can cause multi-collisions (3+ objects) to fail, though.